# Why do i keep getting "Cannot Connect to Server" error when starting SQL management tool?

Tags: sql-server

Why do i keep getting this error when starting SQL management tool?

[image: error message attached]

Comment: The Sql Server Instance doesn't Exists.

Comment: but it works at work, but doesnt when i am at home, do i re install?

Comment: ........ You aren't on your work network at home, so no it isn't going to work....

Comment: You are on a different network at work I assume.   Are you connecting a local server?

Comment: how do i correct it? I am New to sql and i got assignments to do this weekend. please help!!!

Comment: When you say "it works at work" but then say "I got assignments to do" are you employed at a business or studying at university? If you need to connect to a university you might be able to find the information from their web site.

Answer (score 1):

At work you will be on a private network, at home you will probably need to connect to your work network via a VPN.

It's very rare to find a SQL Server instance available on the public internet.

Check the IP address of the server. I'm assuming it will start 10.x.x.x or 192.x.x.x. If so, it is most certainly on a private network.

Comment: how do i correct it? I am New to sql and i got assignments to do this weekend. please help!!!

Comment: If you just need a SQL instance to do some queries take a look at [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) or similar sites where you can run queries; or download a SQLite editor. If you need to get data from the server then you will need to know how to connect to your work network, which is not normally something you will be able to do without an administrator.